# How to put a Virtualized ListView inside a StackPanel or Flyout?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `ListView` inside a `flyout` and `flyout` like `StackPanel` has infinite height so the ListView looses Virtualization.

```
<Flyout Placement="Full">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="All Players" Margin="12"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Margin="12"/>
    </Grid>
</Flyout>
```

I can give a fixed `Height = 500` to Grid, but it may change on different resolutions.

I need to get page height and set it in binding but I don't know how to get it!

How can I limit height of ListView?

Comment: You can use {Binding Height, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to SizeChanged event of a Page and set the Height from code behind:

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set the <Grid Name="GridInsideFlyout"> in XAML
        GridInsideFlyout.Height = e.NewSize.Height;
    }
```